# Convert WEBM file to WAV file with Python

Tags: python, audio, wav, webm

I want to convert webm files to wav files with Python to analyze. Is there any simple way to do the conversion from webm to wav in Python?

I looked through all questions here and on google. I know there are some possibilities, but i can't convert the files locally with ffmpeg or convert them with the API from cloudconverter website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! You can do this using `ffmpeg` without Python, but if you want to use Python install the package `MoviePy`. `pip` install it like so:

```
pip install MoviePy
```

Then you can use it in your program:

```
import moviepy.editor as moviepy
clip = moviepy.VideoFileClip("in_video.webm")
clip.audio.write_audiofile("out_audio.wav")
```

Note: with some versions of `MoviePy`, you might have to use `clip.write_audiofile(...)` instead of `clip.audio.write_audiofile(...)`.

Comment: with current version 

`clip.write_audiofile("out_audio.wav")` works instead of `clip.audio.write_audiofile("out_audio.wav")`

Comment: I am getting an error -failed to read the duration of file..Please help

Comment: `clip.audio.write_audiofile()` worked for me,but `clip.write_audiofile()` did not. Using version `1.0.3`.